# What is the intuition behind excluding the effect of gravity from accelerometer data

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, reference-frames, acceleration, sensor

In the unit of accelerometer and linear acceleration, I see that accelerometer is angular and the linear acceleration is linear. There is the impact of gravity on the accelerometer. However, considering a wearable sensor, for example, a smart bracelet, suppose that we have a 3-axis accelerometer sensor in it. Suppose that we only move our wrist on $z$-axis (ex. move up) without moving on the $x$- and $z$-axis. linear acceleration on $z$-axis gives us our speed (m/s^2) but what accelerometer does. I have some difficulties imagining the value given by z-axis of the accelerometer. What means, visually, angular acceleration?

Example of a case: Suppose that I am walking and I hand my phone to my friend who is walking next to me. I am interested in how I hand the phone. I want to work on the pattern of this. For example: Let's say I'm looking for the answer to the question of whether each person has a unique phone handing pattern. Let the sensor be a sensor integrated into the smartphone.

Comment: It depends on what you are doing with the sensor. You refer to materials not provided so we cannot know what you are talking about.

Comment: @DKNguyen, Suppose that I am walking and I hand my phone to my friend who is walking next to me. I am interested in how I hand the phone. I want to work on the pattern of this. For example: Let's say I'm looking for the answer to the question of whether each person has a unique phone handing pattern. Let the sensor be a sensor integrated into the smartphone.

Comment: @MasA Your question starts with "In their formulation, I see that one is angular and the other one is linear."  We have no idea who "their" refers to, or what "one" and "the other one" might be.  Please clarify what you're talking about.  We can't answer without understanding what you're asking.

Comment: I tried to revise my question. I hope it is better now.

Comment: If you are analyzing a motion event that does not care about gravity, and gravity is always there and the same direction, what does it contribute to your analysis other than offset errors? That drift with time no less.

Comment: This is a good question. It is the same as asking how a drone keeps track of the g vector as it flies around and and does stunts like flipping or banking. The small drones use the same 3 axis accelerators and gyros (often in a single chip) as phones. Answers are more likely to be found by searching for drone control algorithms and inertial navigation and the math behind them. Try a search on "the math of drone control". It produces some promising pages.

Answer (score 1):

You are not only ignoring gravity. You are also ignoring the force from the ground that holds you up. If only gravity acted on you, you would be in free fall. The force from the ground that prevents free fall is equal and opposite to gravity. So the total force you are ignoring is $0$.

One (not necessarily practical) way to make a z-axis accelerometer would be to put a bead on a vertical wire and attach the bead to a string. If the accelerometer accelerates in the vertical direction, the bead will get left behind. The wire will move upward, compressing the spring. The compressed spring will push upward on the bead until it moves along with the rest of the accelerometer. You measure acceleration by measuring the compression of the spring.

Sitting still, the weight of the bead compresses the spring. You mark that length as an acceleration of $0$.

In free fall, the spring would be longer. You mark that length as an acceleration of $1$ g downward.

You mark other lengths similarly.

There are better ways to make an accelerometer, but this should help you see how they are affected by gravity.